# Exporting Access form to Excel wth excluded fields

Tags: ms-access, export, export-to-excel

I have a continuous form, where the form header contains filter options, and the details section contains the data.

I want to be able to export this using the built-in export to excel functionality provided with access 2007. I can currently do this, and it works without error except for one small issue.

When I export to Excel, it also includes the form header controls for each row. Is there any way to set a property that will exclude the form header from being included in the export? Basically, only export the form details section?

Comment: Do you actually want to export the form itself to Excel, or just the data displayed in the form?

Comment: Just the data. Just want them to be able to export the results of the form via the export option in the ribbon.

Comment: I don't believe that ribbon option offers the kind of flexibility to do what you want here.  I suspect you'll need to write VBA code for this.